# Missing IDA PRO Mach-O file for ARMv6 support

Tags: iphone, arm, mach-o, ida, armv6

I've just downloaded IDA Pro 6.4 demo version and when i try to open an iPhone binary file i can only chose "Macho-O file (EXECUTE).ARMv7 [macho.ldw]".

I've seen people having to chose between ARMv6 and ARMv7 on their IDA Pro version.
I need that ARMv6 option, the correct macho.ldw file.

Any idea where to find it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently your file just does not contain an ARMv6 part.